# Algorithm to find matching real values in a list

Tags: algorithm, iteration, numeric, numerical-methods

I have a complex algorithm which calculates the result of a function f(x). In the real world f(x) is a continuous function. However due to rounding errors in the algorithm this is not the case in the computer program. The following diagram gives an example:

[image]

Furthermore I have a list of several thousands values Fi.

I am looking for all the x values which meet an Fi value i.e. f(xi)=Fi

I can solve this problem with by simply iterating through the x values like in the following pseudo code:

```
for i=0 to NumberOfChecks-1 do
begin

  //calculate the function result with the algorithm
  x=i*(xmax-xmin)/NumberOfChecks;
  FunctionResult=CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x);

  //loop through the value list to see if the function result matches a value in the list
  for j=0 to NumberOfValuesInTheList-1 do
  begin
    if Abs(FunctionResult-ListValues[j])<Epsilon then
    begin
      //mark that element j of the list matches 
      //and store the corresponding x value in the list
    end
  end

end
```

Of course it is necessary to use a high number of checks. Otherwise I will miss some x values. The higher the number of checks the more complete and accurate is the result. It is acceptable that the list is 90% or 95% complete.

The problem is that this brute force approach takes too much time. As I mentioned before the algorithm for f(x) is quite complex and with a high number of checks it takes too much time.

What would be a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer, but the behavior of the plot, deemed to represent a continuous function, doesn't inspire comfidence. "Rounding errors" must be quite severe to expain such irregularity.

Comment: @Yves Agree, the rounding errors seem to cause variations of 10-20 % of the f(x) result - that is big, indeed. Also it's rather hard to propose good solutions without knowing the numeric distribution of the thousands of Fi values. Are they closeby/randomly distributed/what? Can one Fi value match multiple f(x)'s or are the Fi-values also a fn of x (where x in this case is "index")?  They could have been included in the plot as well...

Comment: The algorithm which represents f(x) is a propagation alogorithm trough tousands of elements. Therefore the rounding errors accumulate.

Comment: @Stormwind The Fi-values are randomly distributed. However the list of the Fi-values is an ordered array.

Comment: @Stormwind Due to the rounding errors it is possible that several x values result in the same f(x)-value (respectively Fi-vaule). But I need to find only one x value per Fi-value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this is in two parts: generate all of the results, sort them, and then merge with the sorted list of existing results.

First step is to compute all of the results and save them along with the `x` value that generated them. That is:

```
results = list of <x, result>

for i = 0 to numberOfChecks
    //calculate the function result with the algorithm
    x=i*(xmax-xmin)/NumberOfChecks;
    FunctionResult=CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x);
    results.Add(x, FunctionResult)
end for
```

Now, sort the `results` list by `FunctionResult`, and also sort the `FunctionResult-ListValues` array by result.

You now have two sorted lists that you can move through linearly:

```
i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < results.length && j < ListValues.length)
{
    diff = ListValues[j] - results[i];
    if (Abs(diff) < Episilon)
    {
        // mark this one with the x value
        // and move to the next result
        i = i + 1
    }
    else if (diff > 0)
    {
        // list value is much larger than result. Move to next result.
        i = i + 1
    }
    else
    {
        // list value is much smaller than result. Move to next list value.
        j = j + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Jim Mischel This will improve the performance. But only by about 10%. The reason is that `CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x)` is complex and time consuming. I need to try to get the number of calls to `CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x)` down.

Comment: @user3384674: As far as I can tell, this only calls `CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x)` once for each `x` value. That's the best you can do under the circumstances. The other way would be to improve the function to eliminate (or reduce) the rounding errors that cause the problem in the first place. But since we don't know what that is . . .

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort the list, producing an array `SortedListValues` that contains
   the sorted `ListValues` and an array `SortedListValueIndices` that
   contains the index in the original array of each entry in
   `SortedListValues`. You only actually need the second of these and
   you can create both of them with a single sort by sorting an array
   of tuples of (value, index) using value as the sort key.
2. Iterate over your range in `0..NumberOfChecks-1` and compute the
   value of the function at each step, and then use a binary chop
   method to search for it in the sorted list.

Pseudo-code:

```
// sort as described above
SortedListValueIndices = sortIndices(ListValues);

for i=0 to NumberOfChecks-1 do
begin

  //calculate the function result with the algorithm
  x=i*(xmax-xmin)/NumberOfChecks;
  FunctionResult=CalculateFunctionResultWithAlgorithm(x);

  // do a binary chop to find the closest element in the list
  highIndex = NumberOfValuesInTheList-1;
  lowIndex = 0;
  while true do
  begin
     if Abs(FunctionResult-ListValues[SortedListValueIndices[lowIndex]])<Epsilon then
     begin
       // find all elements in the range that match, breaking out
       // of the loop as soon as one doesn't
       for j=lowIndex to NumberOfValuesInTheList-1 do
       begin
         if Abs(FunctionResult-ListValues[SortedListValueIndices[j]])>=Epsilon then    
           break
         //mark that element SortedListValueIndices[j] of the list matches 
         //and store the corresponding x value in the list
       end
       // break out of the binary chop loop
       break
     end

     // break out of the loop once the indices match
     if highIndex <= lowIndex then
        break

     // do the binary chop searching, adjusting the indices:
     middleIndex = (lowIndex + 1 + highIndex) / 2;
     if ListValues[SortedListValueIndices[middleIndex] < FunctionResult then
         lowIndex = middleIndex;
     else          
     begin
         highIndex = middleIndex;        
         lowIndex = lowIndex + 1;
     end
  end
end
```

Possible complications:

- The binary chop isn't taking the epsilon into account. Depending on
  your data this may or may not be an issue. If it is acceptable that
  the list is only 90 or 95% complete this might be ok. If not then
  you'll need to widen the range to take it into account.
- I've assumed you want to be able to match multiple x values for each FunctionResult. If that's not necessary you can simplify the code.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally this depends very much on the data, and especially on the numeric distribution of Fi. Another problem is that the f(x) looks very jumpy, eliminating the concept of "assumption of nearby value".

But one could optimise the search.

Picture below.

1. Walking through F(x) at sufficient granularity, define a rough **min**
   (red line) and **max** (green line), using suitable tolerance (the "air"
   or "gap" in between). The area between min and max is "AREA".
2. See where each Fi-value **hits** AREA, do a **stacked marking** ("MARKING") at X-axis accordingly (can be multiple segments of X).
3. Where lots of MARKINGs at top of each other (higher sum - the vertical black "sum" arrows), do **dense hit tests**, hence increasing the overall
   chance to get as many hits as possible. Elsewhere do more sparse tests.
4. Tighten this schema (decrease tolerance) as much as you dare.
5. EDIT: Fi is a bit confusing. Is it an ordered array or does it have random order (as i assumed)?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding point 5: Fi is a ordered array.

Comment: But if you are looking for locations where Fi-value[x] == f(x), why don't you then walk through all x's that Fi covers, and check? Sure there cannot be any other way to know? Either Fi-value[x] == f(x) or it is not?

Comment: @ Stormwind I am not sure if I understand your question completely. I am looking for one x value for 90% or 95% of the values in the Fi values list. But I do not have the reverse function of f(x).

Comment: We just comminucate badly :-). I mean: __Scenario 1)__ Consider that Fi[42] == f(42) - is that a hit? __Scenario 2)__ Consider that Fi[24] == f(42) - is that a hit? If /2/ is valid, then my answer __may__ help, depending on how the Fi-values are distributed. Ie. in that case it is irrelevant what the index x of an Fi-value is, and to start with the Fi-values are valid for __all__ x's (as i have painted; the magenta __lines - not points__). If otoh only /1/ is valid, then i wondered why you don't just test for all x-indexes? I guess they are 0...2999 if you have 3000 numbers?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a plot of the Fi-values to the question? Easier when one can see it all.

Answer (score 2):

Jim Mischel's solution would work in a O(i+j) instead of the O(i*j) solution that you currently have. But, there is a (very) minor bug in his code. The correct code would be :

```
    diff = ListValues[j] - results[i]; //no abs() here
    if (abs(diff) < Episilon) //add abs() here
    {
        // mark this one with the x value
        // and move to the next result
        i = i + 1
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the best methods will relay on the nature of your function f(x).

1. The best solution is if you can create the reversing to `F(x)` and use it
2. as you said `F(x)` is continuous:
   therefore you can start evaluating small amount of far points, then find ranges that makes sense, and refine your "assumption" for x that `f(x)=Fi`
   it is not bullet proof, but it is an option.

   e.g. `Fi=5.7; f(1)=1.4 ,f(4)=4,f(16)=12.6, f(10)=10.1, f(7)=6.5, f(5)=5.1, f(6)=5.8`, you can take `5 < x < 7`
3. on the same line as #1, and IF `F(x)` is hard to calculate, you can use Interpolation, and then evaluate `F(x)` only at the values that are probable.